# Hadoop mkdir connection refused, how to check the connection and fix it

Tags: java, hadoop, connection-refused

I have my hadoop installed following this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VhxWig96dME
and run well on two machines (laptop and server). However when I repeat the steps for the third machine, it run well until I try this command:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /input
```

the error message is:
[image]

What can I check and fix here? 
I have one suspect is that this machine have something block the connection or port (normally I also use xampp for php but now it is not running).

Comment: You could be possibly right, first make sure that if the firewall in the newly added server is disabled... It could also block access to the ports..

Comment: how could I make sure that ? Is there anyway to check? I run start-yarn from sbin and it looks like quite normal.

Comment: Check `netstat -anp | grep <hdfs port>` in the new machine...and from any other machine check `telnet <new server ip> <hdfs port>`...and see if you getting any results..

Comment: And which Linux version do you use?

Comment: Does `jps` command list all hadoop processes?

Comment: jps returns: 7600 Jps; 11532 DataNode; 11980 ResourceManager; I am using windows 7.

Comment: could you post your /etc/hosts?